# Filter elements from the end of a list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
```

What is the best way to filter out only tuples at the end of the list where the second element is 0?

The desired output is:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10)]
```

Comment: How are you defining "the end of the list"? (6,0) isn't at the end of the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds to me like you want a '`rstrip()` for lists'. You can use `.pop()` with a while loop:

```
while somelist and somelist[-1][1] == 0:
    somelist.pop()
```

This alters the list *in place*.

To create a copy, you'd have to first find a slice end-point, then slice up to that point for a quick copy:

```
end = len(somelist)
while end and somelist[end - 1][1] == 0:
    end -= 1
newlist = somelist[:end]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [355]: list(reversed(list(dropwhile(lambda x: x[1]==0, reversed([(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10), (6, 0), (7, 0)])))))
Out[355]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the solution by @MartijnPieters for in-place

```
>>> L = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
>>> i = next((i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(reversed(L)) if y != 0), 0)
>>> L[:-i]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By your question, I interpreted that you only wanted to remove the elements with the second value as 0. If this is not what you meant, I apologize.
You can do this (if you want to permanently alter the list):

```
myList = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i][1] == 0:
        del myList[i]
return myList
```

Or if you do not want to alter the list, you can do this:

```
myList = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 0), (5, 10), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
afterList = []
for i in myList:
    if i[1] != 0:
        afterList.append(i)
return afterList
```

Comment: Your first example will produce an `IndexError`.

Comment: This removes elements the OP wanted to keep.

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome: Run it. Your loop drops elements from the list, so `for i in range(len(mylist))` will loop too many times.

Comment: Never mind I realized what was wrong with the example. As the numbers are deleted, the length of the list changes. Sorry 'bout that.